# If I integrate $∫1 dx^2 $, do I get $\frac{1}{2}x^2+Cx+D$?

Tags: calculus, integration

If I integrate $∫1dx^2$ , do I get $\frac{1}{2}x^2+Cx+D$? Let me know if I have any misunderstandings.

Can I integrate $1$ with respect to the second derivative of $x$ to get $\frac{1}{2}x^2+Cx+D$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $\int 1 d(x^{2})=\int  2xdx=x^{2}+C$.

Comment: Sorry I'll update the question, I meant can I integrate 1 with respect to the second derivative of x to get (1/2)x^2 + Cx + D. Thanks for you help BTW!

Comment: do you mean doing indefinite integral twice? In that case you need two $\int$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yeah that what I'm trying to do. Can you please show me another source that says that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by $\int1dx^2$ you mean $\int(\int1dx)dx$ then yes...

$$\int\bigg(\int1dx\bigg)dx=\int\big(x+C\big)dx=\int{x}dx+\int{Cdx}$$

$$={x^2\over2}+Cx+D$$

However, your notation is incorrect because $\int1dx^2$ means;

$$\int{dx^2}=\int2xdx=x^2+C$$

Answer (score 1):

From your answer, I suppose your question is to find the solution of
$$ f''(x) = 1 $$
then
$$ f'(x) = \int f''(x) \; \text{d}x$$
RHS is an indefinite integral, so the possible solutions for $f'(x)$ are not unique. Say $$\int f''(x) \; \text{d}x = G(x) + C$$
then solutions for $f(x)$ are
$$ f(x) = \int f'(x) \;\text{d}x = \int G(x) + C \; \text{d} x = \int G(x)\; \text{d} x \; + Cx $$
and of course, RHS is again an indefinite integral. So all possible solutions are
$$ f(x) = H(x) + Cx + D$$
if
$$ \int G(x)\; \text{d} x \; = H(x) + D$$
In this case take $H(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$ and hence the answer.

---

By the way, writing
$$ f(x)  = \int \int f''(x) \; \text{d}x \; \text{d}x$$
would be unprecise imo(since $\int f''(x) \; \text{d}x$ is the set of all possible functions rather than an actual function, and it as a function isn't clear what its variable is).
If I were to write something like this, I would instead write
$$ f(z)  = \int^z \int^y f''(x) \; \text{d}x \; \text{d}y$$
which is still not very precise, but better imo.